# Why is there a delay in java script timer?

Tags: javascript, timer, ionic-framework, mobile-website

I am trying to use java script and ionic to build hybrid mobile web app. I have a timer functionality where you click on the start button and timer should start.

Here is someone's js fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/AbrGL/

```
function startClock() {
    if (clicked === false) {
        clock = setInterval("stopWatch()", 1000);
        clicked = true;
    }
    else if (clicked === true) {
    }
}
```

When you click on start button, we have a slight delay (like 1 second) before the counter starts.

Is there a way to make this faster ?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work...! You got the names of several functions wrong, check your uppercase and lowercase!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP posted an answer requesting that the question be closed.

Comment: Actually there are some good answer there which can be useful, I don't mind if it stays open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the 1000 milliseconds parameter to zero, or some really low number.  The caveat here is that some browsers have a minimum of 10 or 20 milliseconds when firing intervals so there may be glitches, overlapping and other unintended results.

You can also add in a maximum number of times the interval fires as well for additional control.

```
clock = setInterval("stopWatch()", 20, 2);
```

The clock variable will now repeat every 20 milliseconds for a total of 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

```
function startClock() {
    if (clicked === false) {
        clock = setInterval(stopWatch, 1000); // invoke it every second from now
        stopWatch(); // invoke it now
        clicked = true;
    }
    else if (clicked === true) {
    }
}
```